# Filtering results for post_type tells me I don't have permission

Tags: custom-post-types, permissions

I have a post type that for some reason I am unable to access.

Here is the message I get when I try to access it:

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

edit.php?post_type=alt

How can I change the permission? How can I find why it is blocking a certain user?

**UPDATE**

I use `register_post_type()` and in it I added `'assign_terms' => "edit_alt"`. But when I `var_dump( "$tax->cap->assign_terms" );` the `'assign_terms'` is back to `'edit_posts'`.

I think this is the source of the problem. But how do I correct this?

Comment: Please read about users, [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) in Codex. Then improve your question with what you've tried so far. And please update your question with the code that you use (incl. the hook where it's attached) to register that specific post type.

Comment: Is this issue [related to this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125522/how-can-i-add-a-new-custom-status-for-post-publishing)? Having a custom post status might trigger post transition hooks your install isn't prepared for (in code). As well mapped meta capabilities might bring up such issues.

Comment: Ok I think I clear up the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes I have a custom post_type. I use the "register_post_type" and in it I added 'assign_terms' => "edit_alt",. But when I var_dump "$tax->cap->assign_terms" the 'assign_terms' is back to 'edit_posts'.

Comment: @kaiser you're right, well I think you are, that these two problems are related.